# Vue compile when inserting in DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to insert a compiled element into the `DOM`, however it will be inserted into a random place, not in a pre-defined location as is documentation...

```
var res = Vue.compile('<div><span>{{ msg }}</span></div>')
new Vue({
  data: {
    msg: 'hello'
  },
  render: res.render,
  staticRenderFns: res.staticRenderFns
})
```

All approaches with `V-for`, `V-if/show` will not serve as they also require predefined elements.

I tried something like this...

```
document.getElementById('elPai').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', Vue.compile('<div><span>{{ msg }}</span></div>'));
```

It returns an object containing ' render ' and ' StaticRenderFns ', but did not find the result compiled on these objects, it seems to me that it is recorded in a ' Promisse ', which is triggered when the element is predefined in ' DOM '.

Finally, there is how to insert elements compiled into DOM with ' Vue 2 '?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you provide us with more information about exactly what you're trying to achieve? If you can't achieve this with a single HTML template, then you might need to resort to a custom render function. Or maybe you can just split your components up into smaller pieces and compose them that way.

Comment: It is basically a compile of angularjs however at Vue, $mount it worked for me but fails to recognise the functions when compiled https://jsfiddle.net/044euft5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var MyComponent = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div>Hello!</div>'
})

new MyComponent().$mount('#app')
```

Example from:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount

Comment: It worked, the element is compiled however, cannot find the function https://jsfiddle.net/044euft5/

Comment: Only functions defined inside components will work. There are different ways to communicate between components just check google (e.g. https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860)

Comment: Perfect! I will leave my solution here for future references https://jsfiddle.net/044euft5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right, but for mounting it, you use [`.$mount()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount) (like in @Wszerad's answer):

```js
console.clear();

var res = Vue.compile('<div><span>{{ msg }}</span></div>');

console.log(res);

var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    msg: 'hello'
  },
  render: res.render,
  staticRenderFns: res.staticRenderFns
});

vm.$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.5/dist/vue.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```